# HTTP/2 on a mixed infra

Tags: java, http, server, webserver, http2

We have F5 load balancers in the front which is open to internet.

There is support for HTTP/2 in F5. Behind F5 load balancers there are Apache HTTP servers from IBM and behind HTTP servers we have Websphere Application servers.

So my question is can I meet the traffic with F5 and HTTP/2. However behind F5 there is no support for HTTP/2.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. Similar to this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy/41647983#41647983