# Deploy http2 to l7 load balanced pool of webservers

Tags: webserver, load-balancing, http2

I have to implement http2 on a website and going through the implementation plan.
The infrastructure is as such :

`Users ( connecting over tcp 443 only )
       |
       V
     asa fw
       | 
       V
     l7 lb    ( ssl/tls terminates here and least connection load balancing )
     /    \     encrypted communication using self signed cert between
     V    V         lb and web servers
   web01  web02`

Question is :

in order to have the wesite fully http2 compliant ( https, multiplexing, server push, and the like ... ) do both lb and web servers have to support http2 ? Or only the web servers ?

I belive both of them need to support http2, for reasons such as : a) this is a layer7 lb hence http protocol aware b) the termination happens on the lb c) the full journey visitor to webserver must be http2 compliant.
But as I am not an expert on the subject, I'd like if anyone out there could share their personal experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to support HTTP2 where the HTTPS terminates.

Not sure why you think you NEED to be fully HTTP2 compliant - most of the benefits, at least at present until server push becomes more mainstream are gained by being HTTP/2 at end point. See here for more info:
[HTTP2 with node.js behind nginx proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy)