# If I have upgraded nginx to support http/2, then ask the next need to upgrade Tomcat to support http/2?

Tags: tomcat, nginx, http2

Now, Tomcat and nginx have been supporting http/2,Our online service has been deployed nginx, to support http/2. 
Then ask the next need to upgrade Tomcat to support http/2?
The request process is as follows,Most requests go through tomcat,I think upgrade Tomcat is some benefits, but not sure.
If you have a study of this, be grateful

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLwZt.png)

Comment: It depends on how nginx communicates with Tomcat, if at all. If it uses AJP for example it's irrelevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP2 with node.js behind nginx proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy)

Answer (score 1):

There's no necessity and no benefit in this topology, because NGINX will only use HTTP/1.1 for the backend connection.  HTTP/2 on the backend connection isn't supported.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For a question, has It mention this in public information, or mention  later supports HTTP / 2 in the next release