# should I run nodejs in http2 when nginx is host http2

Tags: node.js, nginx, http2

I was running Web App on NodeJS v8.4 to try http2.
I run some test and found out some interesting result.
Here is three test scenario:

1. nginx listen `443 ssl http2` <--> redirect to nodejs run http2
2. nginx listen `443 ssl http2` <--> redirect to nodejs run http
3. nginx listen `443 ssl` <--> redirect to nodejs run http

I open chrome dev tool to check which protocol is used when loading resources.
The result is first two methods all run in `http2` and Waterfall is almost the same.
The last one is run in `http1.1` and the waterfall is as expected

I wana make sure if I need to run NodeJS in http2 when nginx is host in http2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP2 with node.js behind nginx proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy)

Comment: thanks. that's what I want to know