# Trying use https, Nginx for ssl termination and Varnish is serving the content. But it is not going through http2

Tags: nginx, https, varnish, http2

I am trying to upgrade to varnish 5.2. I wanted to support htttps,so setup nginx at front end. Now any https (http2) request is terminated and http 1.1 request is reaching varnish instead http2. Http2 feature enabled in varnish.nginx will not support http2 for any upstream requests,but wanted to know any other reverse proxy like hitch will support http2 to upstream to varnish. Any other tweak required to send http2 request to varnish??. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx only supports HTTP/2 for incoming connections and not for proxy pass connections and have [no plans to add this](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/923).

Apache does support this with mod_proxy_http2 though [this is still marked as experimental at the time of writing](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http2.html).

However I’m not sure why you think you need HTTP/2 for varnish? See my answer to this question for more discussion on this: [HTTP2 with node.js behind nginx proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy/41647983)