# Best option for http2 protocol for Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http2, spdy

Hi I'm building an app in Node, using the Express framework.

I want to add http2 support and these are the options I've came across:

1. [Node.js HTTP/2](https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html)
2. [node-spdy](https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy)

My favorite is **node-spdy**, I've already implemented it and it works perfectly.
But I'm wandering if it's the right choice?

**Node.js HTTP/2** as "native" solution seems like a great choice as well.
Should I stick with **node-spdy** or transition to the "native" **http2**?

I don't have much experience with these two, so any helpful information or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As you see **HTTP/2** is still a experimental feature in Node.js. (https://nodejs.org/api/http2.html#http2_http_2)

I would recommend you to stick to **node-spdy** until its stable.

Also its not back compatible with **HTTP/1** so you need to handle your own fallback

Comment: It's also good to know that some features like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy has no plans to be implemented.

Comment: It is no longer experimental