# How to server HTTP/2 Protocol with django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, http2, django-wsgi

I am planing to deploy my Django application with HTTP/2 protocol but I'm unable to find the proper solution. How can I serve my Django web application with HTTP/2, the only thing that I find is [hyper-h2](https://github.com/python-hyper/hyper-h2/tree/master/examples/asyncio).

I read the documentation but unable to setup the connections.

Answer (score 14):

## You can do with Nginx proxy

if you have existing nginx config. you do by just adding a word .**http2** in  listen

```
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
```

full document avaliable in

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-with-http-2-support-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Knowing that gunicorn doesn't support http2, this can be enough ?

Comment: Should be enough as Nginx is going to terminate the connection here and will connect with gunicorn via another internal set protocol/channel.

Answer (score 5):

One option is to use Apache httpd server with mod_wsgi. Apache supports terminating HTTP/2. The link to your Django application is still via WSGI API so you don't really get any access to HTTP/2 specific features in your application. You can though configure Apache to do things like server push on your behalf.

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_http2.html

Comment: Agreed and there is little need to speak it all the way through: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy

Answer (score 4):

To support HTTP 2.0, You can deploy Django apps on web servers like Daphne using ASGI (which is the spiritual successor to WSGI).

you can read more about deploying Django with ASGI in the [official documentaion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/asgi/)

to read more about ASGI and what is it, [introduction to ASGI](https://asgi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html)
to read more about Daphne server, [official repository](https://github.com/django/daphne)