# Running django app on http/2 or http/2 protocol instead of http/1

Tags: python-3.x, django, http

Our website is developed using Django 2.1 and it is serving on http/1 protocol, We have set up it on shared Cpanel hosting, So Cpanel gives a graphical interface to handle it.

Is there any way, we can switch protocol programmatically or any other ways to do this?

Please advice,

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to server HTTP/2 Protocol with django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51225433/how-to-server-http-2-protocol-with-django)

Comment: Yes, it can be if we use VPS or a dedicated server, but in shared hosting, you don't have that much access to run the commands, So we contacted the hosting service provider and they solved this issue from their side. 
Thank you @metatoaster for your time