# Does only my web server proxy need to support HTTP 2/3

Tags: node.js, express, http, nginx, http2

I run an ExpressJS website in a docker container forwarded to a localhost port. I use NGINX to proxy and push it to the internet with caching, SSL, and all of the normal things.

I am wondering how I need to implement HTTP 2 and 3. Similar to SSL, do I only need to use it on my proxy server (NGINX), or does the whole chain need to support it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP2 with node.js behind nginx proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy)