# Tomcat 8.5 - Is HTTP2 relevant to backend to backend communication

Tags: java, http, tomcat8, http2, server-to-server

This isn't a duplicate of [node.js with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy), because I'm asking about Tomcat 8.5 communication java backend server to java backend server

When reading about [HTTP2](https://searchengineland.com/everyone-moving-http2-236716) improvements, most relevant HTTP2 improvements are client related, specifically browser, connection with backend server

We are using HTTP2 for client-server using external provider (cloud flare )

Is it relevant/beneficiary to add change internal backend to backend communication from **HTTP** to **HTTP2**?

Server runs on tomcat 8.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP2 with node.js behind nginx proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637076/http2-with-node-js-behind-nginx-proxy)

Comment: @BarryPollard Thanks, the accepted answer says that *benefits of HTTP/2 are negligible*, but node.js+nginx is different than tomcat 8.5 to tomcat 8.5 communication, no?

Comment: @BarryPollard I found a relevant quote in your book *On intranet sites, latency shouldn’t be as big an issue as on the public internet, so the benefits of moving to HTTP/2 are fewer*

Comment: Why are they different?

Comment: There is no such thing as 'server to server communication'. From the TCP or HTTP point of view one of them is a client.

Comment: @BarryPollard They can be, quote from your answer *Nginx also doesn't, at the time of writing, support HTTP/2 for ProxyPass connections (though Apache does)*

Comment: @user207421 server to server means, no resources (as css,js), not called from frontend framework as javascript, servers on same network, no need for ssl/encryption,...

Comment: Ok but my basic point is that backend to backend (which is what I meant by server to server) doesn’t benefit as much from HTTP/2 as browser to edge server. That doesn’t change whether it’s Tomcat or Node.

Comment: @user7294900 In which case one of the servers is the client of the other. No two ways about it. You can't just invent terminology and expect everybody to understand it.

Comment: @user207421 updated my question to *backend to backend communication*

Comment: @user207421 notice I used site tag terminology`[server-to-server]` while there's no `[backend-to-backend]` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the changes HTTP2 has made are to transform the protocol from a text protocol to a binary protocol, so the more components that speak in the HTTP2 network speed will increase as the binary protocol is more efficient (less traffic)

Comment: Will it be better than using **HTTP** which reduce redundant secure layer? can I use HTTP2  with **HTTP** in tomcat?

Comment: Will it be better than using HTTP which reduce redundant secure layer - yes.. it's much efficiency. can I use HTTP2 with HTTP in tomcat - sorry i don't know