# Nuxt.JS http/2 help and advice

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently building an application using nuxt.js(With the built in server). That said i've been running google light house through development and for the life of me I can't get it to serve http/2.

[image]

Inside the `nuxt.config.js` I added:

```
render: {
    http2: {
      push: true,
      pushAssets: (req, res, publicPath, preloadFiles) => preloadFiles
        .filter(f => f.asType === 'script' && f.file === 'runtime.js')
        .map(f => `<${publicPath}${f.file}>; rel=preload; as=${f.asType}`)
    }
}
```

Maybe i'm not understanding how HTTP/2 works with nuxt, if anyone has any help or advice they can offer that would be great!

Comment: Did you have any success ensuring the nuxt assets serve via http2?

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing Nuxt doesn't seem to support serving HTTP/2 directly.

Most probably due to fact that usually HTTP/2 is enabled on edge (load balancer, CDN, etc) which communicates with your Nuxt server using HTTP/1 ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41647983/855621)).

Nevertheless you can set up Nginx proxy server with HTTP/2 enabled for your Nuxt app:

1. install and set up Nginx ([beginners guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html))
2. generate SSL certificates (HTTP/2 requires HTTPS connection)
3. set up Nginx as reverse https http/2 proxy for your Nuxt app, example configuration:

   ```
   server {
       server_name  localhost_http2;
       listen 3001 ssl http2;

       ssl_certificate /pathTo/server.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /pathTo/server.key;


       location / {
           # url of nuxt app
           proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
           proxy_buffering off;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
       }
   }
   ```
4. Assuming you have nuxt running on http://localhost:3000/, when visiting https://localhost:3001/ your app will be served with HTTP/2