# HTTP2 setup for NodeJS Express on Apache throws Error

Tags: node.js, apache, express, http2

I have trouble setting up HTTP2 for NodeJS v12.19.0/Express App, provided over an Apache server.

I enabled mod *http2* & *proxy_http2* and installed *npm http2*.

The bin/www looks as follows:

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('production:server');
var http = require('http2');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
var port = parseInt(val, 10);
if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
}
if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
}
return false;
}

function onError(error) {
if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
}

var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;
switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
    console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
    process.exit(1);
    break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
    console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
    process.exit(1);
    break;
    default:
    throw error;
}
}

function onListening() {
var addr = server.address();
var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

The Apache site config:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    Protocols h2 http/1.1

    ServerName domain.com
    ProxyRequests On
    #ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    #ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

    ProxyPass / h2://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Without the lines

```
ProxyPass / h2://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

I get:

> Proxy Error
>
> The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
> The proxy server could not handle the request
>
> Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
> Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at domain.com Port 443

If I include those lines I get:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
> unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at [no address given] to
> inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
> log. Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at domain.com Port 443

Help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect from Apache to Node via HTTP/2 over HTTPS (`h2`) but it doesn't look like from your Node code that you are using TLS certificates so I'd guess it is just an HTTP/2 over HTTP server (`h2c`).

So replace these lines:

```
ProxyPass / h2://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

With this:

```
ProxyPass / h2c://localhost:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
```

And it should connect over HTTP/2.

However I'd question the value of this. Mod_proxy_http2 is [still marked as experimental](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_http2.html) and [the value of backend HTTP/2 connections is very much in question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41647983/2144578). If you're looking to experiment in Node with HTTP/2 then shouldn't you be connecting directly than via Apache?

Comment: Still hits me with 502 and 503 error. I also start to think that express doesn't really support the http2 module. Most examples I found were for spdy, which is deprecated. I connected via Apache since I had it running for my Nextcloud anyway. I have not much deployment experience with node and figured it's kind of like a flask thing were I might benefit from full fledged http server functionality.