# How and when to use http2

Tags: node.js, angular, http, http2

I am working in a Nodejs express project. Can I migrate my project to HTTP2. Want to know it's advantage over normal HTTP and complexity of work for change in code.
At front-end I am using Angular 6+.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good article about http1 and http2:
[Difference between http1 and http2](https://medium.com/@factoryhr/http-2-the-difference-between-http-1-1-benefits-and-how-to-use-it-38094fa0e95b)

And also http2 with angularjs:
[Usign http2 with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210947/using-http-2-with-angularjs)