# What is best order for linking font , css and JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have built a static website which i am currently hosting

I have given my current order of linking css , JavaScript and all other files in the html code below

**I would appreciate a lot if someone can confirm if i am placing them all at the most ideal place . Consider the best loading speed and possible override. Not just regarding placement , any recommendations to improve overall performance is also welcome**

As you can see there are total 9 linkings happening in my html , lemme give short summary of them

Head -
1) Google Font 
2) My Main CSS File
3) Font awesome Css file
4) Jquery Library
5) JS file for modal windows
6) JS file for navigation bar

Body -
Those 3 you see at bottom are related to the navigation bar as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Website Name</title>

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modal.js"></script>
  <script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

< -- Content -->

<script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
<script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
<script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This question is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Phil thanks for the heads up. I wasn't even aware of that site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS and JavaScript files operate completely independently from one another; loading a CSS file or a JavaScript file first makes absolutely no difference whatsoever in terms of performance.

Still, there are a few points worth noting:

- External CSS files like Google's Fonts and Font Awesome should be loaded *before* your own CSS file(s), as the order in which you load CSS files affects their [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). You're going to want to override the framework fonts with your own CSS - not the other way around.
- JavaScript files that *depend* on other files must be loaded *after* their dependencies. I assume that several of your plugins depend on jQuery, so you'll want to load jQuery before those plugins.
- Placing `<script>` tags at the bottom of the `<body>` element improves the display speed (as opposed to referencing them in `<head>`), because script interpretation slows down the display.

So, in short, I would recommend the following:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Raleway&display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Content -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/modal.js"></script>
  <script src="js/responsive-nav.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fastclick.js"></script>
  <script src="js/scroll.js"></script>
  <script src="js/fixed-responsive-nav.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering.   I just had one doubt tho.    In the body section after the jquery library linking    there are 5 js files    what if i combine them in 1 file and link that ? Would that make any difference.  I had read somewhere that its better to have single long js file than many small js files

Comment: You're asking about [*Minification*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) in relation to [*Multiplexing in HTTP/2*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517829/what-does-multiplexing-mean-in-http-2). If you have implemented HTTP/2 already, then it's slightly faster to have multiple files. If you're still HTTP/1 (if unsure, then you are), it's slightly faster to have one big file. However, the difference is *very* small; there are hundreds of other things that impact performance more than multiplexing, and you should look elsewhere to improve performance :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a few points:

- `<head>` is loaded before `<body>` because of the placement
- *.js is loaded synchronously and sequentially
- *.css is loaded asynchronously
- It is not enough to maintain optimal loading speed by order of placement

To sum up:

- *.css should be in `<head>`
- Larger *.js should be at the bottom of `<body>`
- Small *.js should be in `<head>`

As long as it doesn't affect the order in which some variables are defined