# Self-Hosting the AMP framework - Performance aspect

Tags: performance, cdn, amp-html

Matt Mower posted a [gist](https://gist.github.com/mdmower/b56e94f0dc36beafb825b0c5e31fceef) explaining how to self-host AMP framework.

One of the benefits he counts is:

> serve AMP pages and the framework from the same host, potentially improving content delivery times.

Before reading this, i thought there isn't a difference in performance, because HTML is served once from my server, then async calls transfer the AMP framework files from official CDN. If self-hosted, AMP framework files will still be served almost the same way, but from my server. So how is self-host AMP framework perform better?

Comment: the topic is 'host of libraries', not 'host of content'. your 'hosted' site would point to hosted javascript rather than amp-javascript. you need to check whether your content, with hosted libs, is in the amp-cache (i can't remember without checking)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that, while the AMP libraries are loaded asynchronously, the AMP runtime (`v0.js`) is still render-blocking for your pages (this is done on purpose using the [AMP CSS boilerplate](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/spec/amp-boilerplate/?format=websites) which hides the page content until the runtime loads).

Assuming your server supports HTTP/2, hosting the runtime alongside your website allows you take advantage of [request multiplexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517829/what-does-multiplexing-mean-in-http-2) and avoids connecting to a different server (the AMP CDN) which normally adds DNS lookup and connection overhead.

However, there are disadvantages to self-hosting the framework:

- Your pages become invalid AMP (this will change in the future).
- AMP's CDN is globally distributed and very performant - if you don't use a similar quality CDN yourself, CDN performance may outweigh the advantages introduced from hosting the runtime on the same server as your website.
- Browsers may have cached the AMP runtime served from the AMP CDN if you previously visited another AMP website (this doesn't apply to browsers with a [double-keyed cache](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/m/#!topic/blink-dev/bSMOY-evrV4) like Chrome).

---

Bottom line is, if you're aiming for higher performance on AMP pages, it's best to start with the tips outlined in [How to make AMP even faster](https://blog.amp.dev/2018/10/08/how-to-make-amp-even-faster/) and [implement server-side rendering](https://blog.amp.dev/2019/08/07/faster-amp-on-the-origin-amp-ssr/). Self-hosting the framework *may* yield additional performance benefits, but for most websites this is likely negligible.

Comment: Two additions: 1. self-hosting the AMP runtime will be supported by the AMP validator in the future. 2. browsers nowadays cache scripts only per origin so cross origin caching is no longer a benefit of loading the AMP runtime from cdn.ampproject.org.