# How does a browser know which response belongs to which request?

Tags: http, networking, network-protocols

Suppose when we request a resource over HTTP, we get a response as shown below:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.co.in

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 20 Apr 2017 10:03:16 GMT
...
```

But when a browser requests many resources at a time, how can it identify which request got which response?

Comment: It doesn’t need to “identify” that, request and response “belong” together automatically.

Comment: does server responds serially so that browser is informed?. This means there is no priority in HTTP.

Comment: No, the requests can happen in parallel. The client just opens multiple connections, and sends one HTTP request over each, so that the response arrives via the same connection. http://blog.catchpoint.com/2010/09/17/anatomyhttp/ explains the basics.

Answer (score 19):

> when a browser requests many resources at a time, how can it identify which request got which response?

A browser can open one or more connections to a web server in order to request resources. For each of those connections the rules regarding [HTTP keep-alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) are the same and apply to both HTTP 1.0 and 1.1:

- If HTTP keep-alive is off, the request is sent by the client, the response is sent by the server, the connection is closed:

  ```
  Connection 1: [Open][Request1][Response1][Close]
  ```
- If HTTP keep-alive is on, one "persistent" connection can be reused for succeeding requests. The requests are still issued serially over the same connection, so:

  ```
  Connection 1: [Open][Request1][Response1][Request3][Response3][Close]
  Connection 2: [Open][Request2][Response2][Request4][Response4][Close]
  ```

With [HTTP Pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining), introduced with HTTP 1.1, if it is enabled (on most browsers it is by default disabled, because of buggy servers), browsers can issue requests after each other without waiting for the response, but the responses are still returned in the same order as they were requested.

- This can happen simultaneously over multiple (persistent) connections:

  ```
  Connection 1: [Open][Request1][Request2][Response1][Response2][Close]
  Connection 2: [Open][Request3][Request4][Response3][Response4][Close]
  ```

Both approaches (keep-alive and pipelining) still utilize the default "request-response" mechanism of HTTP: each response will arrive in the order of the requests on that same connection. They also have the ["head of line blocking" problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-of-line_blocking): if `[Response1]` is slow and/or big, it holds up all responses that follow on that connection.

- Enter HTTP 2 multiplexing: [What is the difference between HTTP/1.1 pipelining and HTTP/2 multiplexing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478967/what-is-the-difference-between-http-1-1-pipelining-and-http-2-multiplexing). Here, a response can be fragmented, allowing a single TCP connection to transmit fragments of different requests and responses intermingled:

  ```
  Connection 1: [Open][Rq1][Rq2][Resp1P1][Resp2P1][Rep2P2][Resp1P2][Close]
  ```

It does this by giving each fragment an identifier to indicate to which request-response pair it belongs, so the receiver can recompose the message.

Comment: what makes sure that if I send request1, request2 and request3 they arrive in the same order I sent them?

Comment: @Fabio nothing makes sure of that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are really asking for [HTTP Pipelining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) here. This is a technique introduced in HTTP/1.1, through which all requests would be sent out by the client in order and be responded by the server in the very same order. All the gory details are now in [RFC 7230, sec. 6.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3.2).

HTTP/1.0 had (or has) a comparable method known as [Keep Alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection#HTTP_1.0). This would allow a client to issue a new request right after the previous has been answered. The benefit of this approach is that client and server no longer need to negotiate through another TCP handshake for a new request/response cycle.

The important part is that in both methods the order of the responses matches the order of the issued requests over one connection. Therefore, responses can be uniquely mapped to the issuing requests by the order in which the client is receiving them: First response matches, first request, second response matches second request, … and so forth.

Comment: The difference between HTTP/1.1's pipelining (which relies on KeepAlive) and HTTP/1.0 is that in the former, the client can issue multiple requests before getting any response, but in HTTP/1.0 the client must wait for the response before issuing a new request.

Comment: @symcbean Nope. HTTP/1.1's pipelining does not rely on Keep Alive, see the link above. HTTP simply assumes the connection being kept open until closed. wrt to request/response order: That's pretty much what I wrote, isn't it?

Comment: "does not rely on Keep Alive" - I am completely confused by this. How do you send multiple requests over a channel that only allows a single request and response?

Comment: @symcbean Simple. You push them down the server's throat (so to speak) and avoid sending a `Connection: close` among their headers safe for the last request. The server will still be free to only answer the first request or the first *n*, depending on how much it is willing to take.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer you are looking for is **TCP**,

HTTP is a protocol that relies on TCP to establish connection between the **Client** and the **Host**

In **HTTP/1.0** a different TCP connection is created for each **request/response pair**,

**HTTP/1.1** introduced pipelining, wich allowed mutiple request/response pair, to reuse a single TCP connection, to boost performance (Didnt work very well)

So the request and the corresponding response are linked by the TCP connection they rely on,

It's then easy to associate a specific request with the response it produced,

PS: HTTP is not bound to use TCP forever, for example google is experimenting  with other transport protocols like **QUIC**, that might end up being more efficient than TCP for the needs of HTTP

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the explanations above consider a browser can open many parallel connections, usually up to 6 to the same server. For each connection it uses a different socket. For each request-response in each socket it is easy to determine the correlation.

Answer (score 0):

1. In each TCP connection, request and response are sequential. A TCP connection can be re-used after finishing a request-response cycle.
2. With HTTP pipelining, a single connection can be multiplexed for
   multiple overlapping requests.
3. In theory, there can be any number[*1] of simultaneous TCP connections, enabling parallel requests and responses.
4. In practice, the number of simultaneous connections is usually limited on the browser and often on the server as well.

[*1] The number of simultaneous connections is limited by the number of ephemeral TCP ports the browser can allocate on a given system. Depending on the operating system, ephemeral ports start at 1024 (RFC 6056), 49152 (IANA), or 32768 (some Linux versions).

So, that may allow up to 65,535 - 1023 = 64,512 TCP source ports for an application. A TCP socket connection is defined by its local port number, the local IP address, the remote port number and the remote IP address. Assuming the server uses a single IP address and port number, the limit is the number of local ports you can use.