# How to send push notifications to multiple devices using Migrate from legacy FCM APIs to HTTP v1 in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i send fcm token in array format but i getting error "field":"message","description":"Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "tokens" at 'message': Cannot find field."

```
$fields = [
           'message' => [
           'tokens' => $fcmIds,
           'notification' => $notificationData,
           'data' => $dataPayload,
            ],
          ];
```

i send like this `FCM` token in array format.

Comment: Batch sending is no longer a separate API call. You should now call the send method for each individual message and use multiplexing to optimize resource usage. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899435/what-is-the-endpoint-for-sending-multiple-message-at-once-without-using-topic-in

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP v1 API does not support batch sending, and it has been deprecated in the legacy API since June 21, 2023, and is set to be removed in June 2024.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-multiple-devices

> Important: The send methods described in this section were deprecated on June 21, 2023, and will be removed in June 2024. For protocol, instead use the standard HTTP v1 API send method, implementing your own batch send by iterating through the list of recipients and sending to each recipient's token. For Admin SDK methods, make sure to update to the next major version. See the Firebase FAQ for more information.

Either you have to make your own batching, where you create and send a message to FCM per device token, as mentioned in the quote above, or you can look into subscribing device tokens to [Topics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/send-multiple).