# How can HTTP pipelining make performance worse?

Tags: http

It's a popular claim that HTTP pipelining can degrade performance of downloading sites due to the head of line (HoL) blocking phenomena. Is this performance compared to a single non-pipelined persistent HTTP connection or to multiple TCP connections opened simultaneously in order to download resources of the site in parallel?

In the first case I can't really see how large response blocking sending subsequential smaller ones can result in performance loss. Yes, this blocking will occur. But in the case of a single non-pipelined persistent HTTP connection the HoL blocking phenomena occurs every time the client sends a request and every time the server sends a response. The only reasons of performance being potentially worse here I was able to think of are that:

1) the time needed to properly queue/buffer requests/responses may be longer that the time saved by the fact that the server can start processing n-th request without waiting for the processing of (n-1)-th request to complete. But it basically comes down to numbering the requests/responses correctly, so it seems to be more of a concern if many small requests have to be dealt with (it's unlikely that queueing/buffering-related computations will take more time than processing a large response and people indicating that HoL blocking can be a problem refer to large responses, not to small ones) and it is not directly related to the HoL blocking;

2) if many clients had pipelining enabled then it is possible that many large responses would have to be buffered effectively leading to memory exhaustion on the server side. But this is a kind of special situation and clearly it is not what people have in mind when speaking about enabling pipeling in a browser being able to make performance worse.

On the other hand, in the case of comparison of pipelining to multiple simultaneous TCP connections it is readily seen that the necessity to send large response before sending subsequential smaller ones will slow things down.

However, if the comparison is made to a single non-pipelined HTTP connection and pipelining can indeed result in performance loss - can you demonstrate some basic (perhaps simplified) calculations showing that?

I tried to search the response to my question on the Internet but was unable to find it.

Some of the resources that I tried:

https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/http-pipelining-a-security-risk-without-real-performance-benefits
[What are the disadvantage(s) of using HTTP pipelining?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14810890/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-http-pipelining)

Comment: Would be great to see more discussion on this

Comment: Similar to how a parallel computer interfaces were dropped, in favor of serial interfaces. Parallelization of data introduces aplenty synchronization issues, which prove to be significant enough to cause substantial packet drop. To counter them it requires more time than it takes for a serial interface to pass data through. Therefore serial > parallel/pipelined.